# copy a sub part of a string

Tags: c, string, memcpy, strcpy

I'm trying to copy a part of a string in a other string.
I know the 2 identifiers starting and ending the sub-string.

I'm trying to copy the IP from this string:

```
0x200085f6 <memp_memory+4502> "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.1.200\r\nConnection
```

The beginning of the string will be "Host: " or 192
The ending will be "\r\nC" or the 2nd occurrence of "\r\n"
So the desired output is:

```
192.168.1.200
```

I tried using strcpy and memcpy but the IP has to be variable so I don't know how long it will be or what it will be, the minimum will be 11 and the maximum 15 chars.

I hope you can help me further.

Comment: Welcome, please edit your question and add your code so far...

Comment: Use regular expressions and you'll have two problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a buffer of 16 bytes (max 3 bytes for each octet, total 12, plus three points is 15, plus zero-terminator).

Then, as you say, you need to precisely position your read:

```
host = strstr(string, "Host: ");
if (!host) {
    // Problem. Cannot continue, the string has not the format expected.
}
host += strlen("Host: ");
end  = strstr(host, "\r\n");
if (!end) {
    // Problem
}
// Sanity check: end - host must be less than 16. Someone could send you
// Host: 192.168.25.12.Hello.I.Am.Little.Bobby.Headers\r\n
if ((end - host) > 15) {
    // Big problem
}
// We now know where the address starts, and where it ends.
// Copy the string into address
strncpy(address, host, (end-host));
// Add zero terminator to make this a C string
address[end-host] = 0x0;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the format of the input string is known, and is as suggested by the posted example input, `sscanf()` can be used with the scanset directive to extract the IP address.

Using `%*[^:]` causes `sscanf()` to match any characters in the input until a colon is encountered. The `*` suppresses assignment. Scanning resumes with the `:` character, so a literal `:` must be placed in the format string to match this character. Then the `%s` directive can be used to match and store the IP address as a string. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUF_SZ  256

int main(void)
{
    const char *input = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.1.200\r\nConnection";

    char ip_address[BUF_SZ];
    if (sscanf(input, "%*[^:]: %255s", ip_address) == 1) {
        puts(ip_address);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
192.168.1.200
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to extract all the characters which are `number` or `.` from the

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.1.200\r\nConnection" till `\r` is encounter.
```

Start extraction after `Host:` 
Remember to terminate the string with '\0'.

Simplified version of the program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {

  char ip[64];
  char *p = NULL;
  char *str = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.1.200\r\nConnection";
  char c;
  int i = 0;
  int len;

  len = strlen("Host ");
  p = strstr(str,"Host: ");

  if(p)
  {    
      while(1)
      {
        c = *(p+i+len);

        if(c != '\r' && c!= '\0')
        {
            if( c == ' '){ 
            i++;
            continue;
            }

            ip[i++] = c;
        }
        else
        {
            ip[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }

     } // while

  }


   printf("Ip=%s", ip);
   return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Ip=192.168.1.200
```

Comment: To be clear, a `'\0'` aka `NUL` byte is the terminator. Don't append the character `'0'`.

Comment: The problem is that this in only a part of the string. It contains more numbers and letters.